# Android: button is disabled and only works after dialog function is executed

Tags: java, android

my button (login) doesn't work unless ImageView (img_log) is pressed and the dialog is clicked.  I do not want my login button disabled.  Please help me debug my code to figure out why my login button only works after the dialog function has been completed

```
public class Register extends Activity {

/**
 *  JSON Response node names.
 **/


private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
private static String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";

/**
 * Defining layout items.
 **/

EditText inputFirstName;
EditText inputLastName;
EditText inputUsername;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
Button btnRegister;
TextView registerErrorMsg;


/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */


public static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
ImageView img_logo;
protected static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 0;
protected static final int GALLERY_PICTURE = 1;
private Intent pictureActionIntent = null;
Bitmap bitmap;


 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.register);

/**
 * Defining all layout items
 **/
    inputFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);
    inputLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
    inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
    registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);





    img_logo= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilepic);
    img_logo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startDialog();
        }

    });
}

 private void startDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    myAlertDialog.setTitle("Upload Pictures Option");
    myAlertDialog.setMessage("How do you want to set your picture?");

    myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Gallery",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    pictureActionIntent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
                    pictureActionIntent.setType("image/*");
                    pictureActionIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                    startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent,
                            GALLERY_PICTURE);
                }
            });

    myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("Camera",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    pictureActionIntent = new Intent(
                            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent,
                            CAMERA_REQUEST);

                }
            });
    myAlertDialog.show();
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICTURE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                // our BitmapDrawable for the thumbnail
                BitmapDrawable bmpDrawable = null;
                // try to retrieve the image using the data from the intent
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(data.getData(),
                        null, null, null, null);
                if (cursor != null) {

                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ImageColumns.DATA);
                    String fileSrc = cursor.getString(idx);
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileSrc); // load
                    Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileSrc);                                                    // preview
                    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, img_logo.getWidth(), img_logo.getHeight(), false);                                                    // image

                    // bmpDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmapPreview);
                    img_logo.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
                } else {

                    bmpDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), data
                            .getData().getPath());
                    img_logo.setImageDrawable(bmpDrawable);
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancelled",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancelled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data.hasExtra("data")) {

                // retrieve the bitmap from the intent
                bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

             //   Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileSrc);                                                    // preview
                Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, img_logo.getWidth(), img_logo.getHeight(), false);                                                    // image

                // bmpDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmapPreview);
                img_logo.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
            } else if (data.getExtras() == null) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "No extras to retrieve!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

                BitmapDrawable thumbnail = new BitmapDrawable(
                        getResources(), data.getData().getPath());

                // update the image view with the newly created drawable
                img_logo.setImageDrawable(thumbnail);

            }

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancelled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }




/**
* Button which Switches back to the login screen on clicked
**/

    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bktologin);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Login.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            finish();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the following code in the `onCreate()` method. Now it is in the `onActivityResult()`  and this is the reason why it doesn't work as desired:

```
Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bktologin);
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Login.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        finish();
    }

});
```